# why does pandas.json_normalize run slower than my hand-crafted loop?

Tags: python, json, pandas, performance

I became suspicious about how fast `pandas.json_normalize` ran in the production environment I was profiling so I wrote a toy program to compare that with some manually crafted `for` loop solution and I don't understand the fact that a more rudimentary(and ugly) solution is so much faster than `json_normalize` provided by `pandas`.

So I created a large array of nested `json` objects for the experiment and compared the performance between three methods:

1. Simply just feed the data to `pandas.json_normalize`
2. use a `for` loop and convert the data to a `dict` that's ready to be fed to `pandas.DataFrame()`. Only part of the data is converted
3. Same as method 2 but with every field.

The structure of each `json` object mimics the production data I currently have.

Here is the full program I have.

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint as pp
import time

# profile pandas json serialization

def _make_large_json_sample(size):
    '''
    the structure would be a list of dictionary. Each dictionary could have
    sub-dictionaries.
    '''

    def _simple_dict(prefix, seed, dsize):

        def _val(prefix, idx, seed):
            if idx in (0, 1): # a datetime value
                return '2021-11-02T05:30:00.%s' % (('%7d' % seed).replace(' ', '0'))
            elif idx in (2, 3): # int
                return int(seed)
            elif idx in (4, 5, 6, 7): # float
                return 10.0*seed
            elif idx == 8: # just a None value
                return None
            else: # string
                return '%s%d for %s' % (prefix, idx, seed)

        return dict(
            (
                '%s%d' % (prefix, _field_idx),
                _val(prefix, _field_idx, seed),
            )
            for _field_idx in range(dsize)
        )

    def _one_element(seed):
        ret = _simple_dict('field', seed, 20)
        ret.update({'outerone' : _simple_dict('innerone', seed, 10)})
        ret.update({'outertwo' : _simple_dict('innertwo', seed, 40)})
        return ret

    return [_one_element(_idx) for _idx in range(size)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    sample = _make_large_json_sample(50000)
    end = time.time()

    print('data generation costs %s seconds' % (end-start)) # around 2.38s
    # pp(sample)

    start = time.time()
    df1 = pd.json_normalize(sample)
    end = time.time()

    print('json normalize costs %s seconds' % (end-start)) # around 8.17s

    # picking fields that are of interest manually
    # say you only need field 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11
    # and outerone.interone0-9
    # and outertwo.intertwo0-4, 10-14
    def _extract_simple_key(key):
        return [element[key] for element in sample]

    def _extract_nest_key(key1, key2):
        return [element[key1][key2] for element in sample]

    def _extract_part():
        return {
            'field1' : _extract_simple_key('field1'),
            'field2' : _extract_simple_key('field2'),
            'field3' : _extract_simple_key('field3'),
            'field4' : _extract_simple_key('field4'),
            'field5' : _extract_simple_key('field5'),
            'field10' : _extract_simple_key('field10'),
            'field11' : _extract_simple_key('field11'),

            'outerone.innerone0': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone0'),
            'outerone.innerone1': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone1'),
            'outerone.innerone2': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone2'),
            'outerone.innerone3': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone3'),
            'outerone.innerone4': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone4'),
            'outerone.innerone5': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone5'),
            'outerone.innerone6': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone6'),
            'outerone.innerone7': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone7'),
            'outerone.innerone8': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone8'),
            'outerone.innerone9': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone9'),

            'outertwo.innertwo0': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo0'),
            'outertwo.innertwo1': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo1'),
            'outertwo.innertwo2': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo2'),
            'outertwo.innertwo3': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo3'),
            'outertwo.innertwo4': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo4'),
            'outertwo.innertwo10': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo10'),
            'outertwo.innertwo11': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo11'),
            'outertwo.innertwo12': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo12'),
            'outertwo.innertwo13': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo13'),
            'outertwo.innertwo14': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo14'),
        }
    start = time.time()
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(_extract_part())
    end = time.time()
    print('partial manual normalization costs %s seconds' % (end-start)) # around 0.78s

    def _extract_full():
        return {
            'field0' : _extract_simple_key('field0'),
            'field1' : _extract_simple_key('field1'),
            'field2' : _extract_simple_key('field2'),
            'field3' : _extract_simple_key('field3'),
            'field4' : _extract_simple_key('field4'),
            'field5' : _extract_simple_key('field5'),
            'field6' : _extract_simple_key('field6'),
            'field7' : _extract_simple_key('field7'),
            'field8' : _extract_simple_key('field8'),
            'field9' : _extract_simple_key('field9'),
            'field10' : _extract_simple_key('field10'),
            'field11' : _extract_simple_key('field11'),
            'field12' : _extract_simple_key('field12'),
            'field13' : _extract_simple_key('field13'),
            'field14' : _extract_simple_key('field14'),
            'field15' : _extract_simple_key('field15'),
            'field16' : _extract_simple_key('field16'),
            'field17' : _extract_simple_key('field17'),
            'field18' : _extract_simple_key('field18'),
            'field19' : _extract_simple_key('field19'),

            'outerone.innerone0': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone0'),
            'outerone.innerone1': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone1'),
            'outerone.innerone2': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone2'),
            'outerone.innerone3': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone3'),
            'outerone.innerone4': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone4'),
            'outerone.innerone5': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone5'),
            'outerone.innerone6': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone6'),
            'outerone.innerone7': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone7'),
            'outerone.innerone8': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone8'),
            'outerone.innerone9': _extract_nest_key('outerone', 'innerone9'),

            'outertwo.innertwo0': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo0'),
            'outertwo.innertwo1': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo1'),
            'outertwo.innertwo2': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo2'),
            'outertwo.innertwo3': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo3'),
            'outertwo.innertwo4': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo4'),
            'outertwo.innertwo5': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo5'),
            'outertwo.innertwo6': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo6'),
            'outertwo.innertwo7': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo7'),
            'outertwo.innertwo8': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo8'),
            'outertwo.innertwo9': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo9'),
            'outertwo.innertwo10': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo10'),
            'outertwo.innertwo11': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo11'),
            'outertwo.innertwo12': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo12'),
            'outertwo.innertwo13': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo13'),
            'outertwo.innertwo14': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo14'),
            'outertwo.innertwo15': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo15'),
            'outertwo.innertwo16': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo16'),
            'outertwo.innertwo17': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo17'),
            'outertwo.innertwo18': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo18'),
            'outertwo.innertwo19': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo19'),
            'outertwo.innertwo20': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo20'),
            'outertwo.innertwo21': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo21'),
            'outertwo.innertwo22': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo22'),
            'outertwo.innertwo23': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo23'),
            'outertwo.innertwo24': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo24'),
            'outertwo.innertwo25': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo25'),
            'outertwo.innertwo26': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo26'),
            'outertwo.innertwo27': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo27'),
            'outertwo.innertwo28': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo28'),
            'outertwo.innertwo29': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo29'),
            'outertwo.innertwo30': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo30'),
            'outertwo.innertwo31': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo31'),
            'outertwo.innertwo32': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo32'),
            'outertwo.innertwo33': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo33'),
            'outertwo.innertwo34': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo34'),
            'outertwo.innertwo35': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo35'),
            'outertwo.innertwo36': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo36'),
            'outertwo.innertwo37': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo37'),
            'outertwo.innertwo38': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo38'),
            'outertwo.innertwo39': _extract_nest_key('outertwo', 'innertwo39'),
        }

    start = time.time()
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(_extract_full())
    end = time.time()
    print('full manual normalization costs %s seconds' % (end-start)) # around 2s
```

An example object in the list looks as follows:

```
>>> pp(sample[1])
{'field0': '2021-11-02T05:30:00.0000001',
 'field1': '2021-11-02T05:30:00.0000001',
 'field10': 'field10 for 1',
 'field11': 'field11 for 1',
 'field12': 'field12 for 1',
 'field13': 'field13 for 1',
 'field14': 'field14 for 1',
 'field15': 'field15 for 1',
 'field16': 'field16 for 1',
 'field17': 'field17 for 1',
 'field18': 'field18 for 1',
 'field19': 'field19 for 1',
 'field2': 1,
 'field3': 1,
 'field4': 10.0,
 'field5': 10.0,
 'field6': 10.0,
 'field7': 10.0,
 'field8': None,
 'field9': 'field9 for 1',
 'outerone': {'innerone0': '2021-11-02T05:30:00.0000001',
              'innerone1': '2021-11-02T05:30:00.0000001',
              'innerone2': 1,
              'innerone3': 1,
              'innerone4': 10.0,
              'innerone5': 10.0,
              'innerone6': 10.0,
              'innerone7': 10.0,
              'innerone8': None,
              'innerone9': 'innerone9 for 1'},
 'outertwo': {'innertwo0': '2021-11-02T05:30:00.0000001',
              'innertwo1': '2021-11-02T05:30:00.0000001',
              'innertwo10': 'innertwo10 for 1',
              'innertwo11': 'innertwo11 for 1',
              'innertwo12': 'innertwo12 for 1',
              'innertwo13': 'innertwo13 for 1',
              'innertwo14': 'innertwo14 for 1',
              'innertwo15': 'innertwo15 for 1',
              'innertwo16': 'innertwo16 for 1',
              'innertwo17': 'innertwo17 for 1',
              'innertwo18': 'innertwo18 for 1',
              'innertwo19': 'innertwo19 for 1',
              'innertwo2': 1,
              'innertwo20': 'innertwo20 for 1',
              'innertwo21': 'innertwo21 for 1',
              'innertwo22': 'innertwo22 for 1',
              'innertwo23': 'innertwo23 for 1',
              'innertwo24': 'innertwo24 for 1',
              'innertwo25': 'innertwo25 for 1',
              'innertwo26': 'innertwo26 for 1',
              'innertwo27': 'innertwo27 for 1',
              'innertwo28': 'innertwo28 for 1',
              'innertwo29': 'innertwo29 for 1',
              'innertwo3': 1,
              'innertwo30': 'innertwo30 for 1',
              'innertwo31': 'innertwo31 for 1',
              'innertwo32': 'innertwo32 for 1',
              'innertwo33': 'innertwo33 for 1',
              'innertwo34': 'innertwo34 for 1',
              'innertwo35': 'innertwo35 for 1',
              'innertwo36': 'innertwo36 for 1',
              'innertwo37': 'innertwo37 for 1',
              'innertwo38': 'innertwo38 for 1',
              'innertwo39': 'innertwo39 for 1',
              'innertwo4': 10.0,
              'innertwo5': 10.0,
              'innertwo6': 10.0,
              'innertwo7': 10.0,
              'innertwo8': None,
              'innertwo9': 'innertwo9 for 1'}}
```

And this is a typical output would look like:

```
(On Ubuntu 20.04, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, Pandas 1.0.1)
data generation costs 2.431631326675415 seconds
json normalize costs 8.036803960800171 seconds
partial manual normalization costs 0.791933536529541 seconds
full manual normalization costs 2.0645904541015625 seconds
```

I tried running it on my company Windows computer and I got very similar results. It used Pandas 1.1.5 there.

I examined the results and these `DataFrame`s look consistent.
I'd really appreciate if you can help me understand the performance discrepancy between these methods.

EDIT:
added environment details

Comment: maybe worth filing a performance issue in [pandas bugtracker](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Performance%2CNeeds+Triage&template=performance_issue.yaml&title=PERF%3A+)

Comment: I don't see the same behavior on a windows laptop                                                 
data generation costs 2.934455633163452 seconds
json normalize costs 2.3622212409973145 seconds
partial manual normalization costs 1.0333595275878906 seconds
full manual normalization costs 2.885122060775757 seconds

Comment: json_normalize is more of a convenience function; you are likely to get more performance when hand crafted. The convenience offered by json_normalize though, especially for nested dictionaries , is amazing

Comment: @JonathanLeon, that's interesting. I ran it on my Windows desktop from work and I got very similar results. The times are 3.3, 11.2, 1.4, 3.7 respectively.

Comment: Yep, just copied the code from above exactly as it is and ran again. json_normalize works just fine and very speedy on my laptop. as a side note, flatte_json is another option for deeply nested json objects. i've seen it be easier to use than json_normalize in some cases

Comment: I should note I'm running python 3.8.2 and pandas 1.3.4; the latest version

Comment: also, this https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/40035 -- seems there were some enhancements made for simpler cases. you may want to upgrade pandas if you can.

Comment: @JonathanLeon, I can confirm that after I upgraded to python3.7 and pandas1.3.4 the performance is great. Looks like it is just the old version.

Comment: good to know, thanks for confirming.