# Looking for a faster way to create a new column in a data frame containing a dictionary values from the rows of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently I have achieved the title by using .apply() with a lambda function:

```
calFilteredDf['startTime'] = calFilteredDf['start'].apply(lambda x: x['dateTime'])
```

This is very slow and I was wondering how I could achieve the same results in less time. calFilteredDf['start'] is a Pandas Series and the data from the 'start' column looks like this:

```
1       {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2021-08-11T15:00:0...
2       {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2021-08-12T09:30:0...
3       {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2021-08-12T10:00:0...
4       {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2021-08-18T11:00:0...
                              ...                        
1692    {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-09T14:00:0...
1693    {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-09T15:00:0...
1694    {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-10T11:30:0...
1695    {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-10T16:00:0...
1696    {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-10T17:00:0...
Name: start, Length: 1697, dtype: object
```

and the data from the new 'startTime' column needs to look like this:

```
1       2021-08-11T15:00:00-04:00
2       2021-08-12T09:30:00-04:00
3       2021-08-12T10:00:00-04:00
4       2021-08-18T11:00:00-04:00
                  ...            
1692    2023-08-09T14:00:00-04:00
1693    2023-08-09T15:00:00-04:00
1694    2023-08-10T11:30:00-04:00
1695    2023-08-10T16:00:00-04:00
1696    2023-08-10T17:00:00-04:00
Name: startTime, Length: 1697, dtype: object
```

Is there a way to do this quickly? I have tried to set

```
calFilteredDf['startTime'] = calFilteredDf['startTime']['dateTime']
```

I've also tried using .loc which didn't work because the rows of 'start' aren't the right data type and I've tried using the swifter library to parallelize the process that .apply() is doing but since the dataset is not very large it actually made it slower because of the extra steps the library preforms to determine what the best way to process the data is.

Comment: For me this operation on 1697 rows takes around 500 microseconds. Is this too slow? How many rows do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pd.json_normalize is more convenient to use, but it turns out to be the slowest. The list generator has become the fastest of all. Below is the pd.json_normalize code. And tests using different approaches.

```
import pandas as pd

aaa = [[{'date': None, 'dateTime': '2021-08-12T09:30'}],
[{'date': None, 'dateTime': '2021-08-12T10:00'}],
[{'date': None, 'dateTime': '2021-08-18T11:00'}],
[{'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-09T14:00'}],
[{'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-09T15:00'}],
[{'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-10T11:30'}],
[{'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-10T16:00'}],
[{'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-10T17:00'}]]


calFilteredDf = pd.DataFrame(aaa)

print(calFilteredDf)

calFilteredDf = pd.json_normalize(calFilteredDf[0])
calFilteredDf['startTime'] = calFilteredDf['dateTime']

print(calFilteredDf)
```

Input

```
                                                0
0  {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2021-08-12T09:30'}
1  {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2021-08-12T10:00'}
2  {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2021-08-18T11:00'}
3  {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-09T14:00'}
4  {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-09T15:00'}
5  {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-10T11:30'}
6  {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-10T16:00'}
7  {'date': None, 'dateTime': '2023-08-10T17:00'}
```

Output

```
   date          dateTime         startTime
0  None  2021-08-12T09:30  2021-08-12T09:30
1  None  2021-08-12T10:00  2021-08-12T10:00
2  None  2021-08-18T11:00  2021-08-18T11:00
3  None  2023-08-09T14:00  2023-08-09T14:00
4  None  2023-08-09T15:00  2023-08-09T15:00
5  None  2023-08-10T11:30  2023-08-10T11:30
6  None  2023-08-10T16:00  2023-08-10T16:00
7  None  2023-08-10T17:00  2023-08-10T17:00
```

Yes, indeed json_normalize is twice as slow. Below is the code where apply, json_normalize, transform, list generator are used.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(10000):
    calFilteredDf[0].apply(lambda x: x['dateTime'])

time_ = datetime.datetime.now() - now
print('apply', time_)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(10000):
    pd.json_normalize(calFilteredDf[0])

time_ = datetime.datetime.now() - now
print('json_normalize', time_)


now = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(10000):
    calFilteredDf[0].transform(lambda x: x['dateTime'])

time_ = datetime.datetime.now() - now
print('transform', time_)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(10000):
    a = [i['dateTime'] for i in calFilteredDf[0]]

time_ = datetime.datetime.now() - now
print('list generator', time_)
```

Output

```
apply 0:00:01.707580
json_normalize 0:00:03.666553
transform 0:00:01.896933
list generator 0:00:00.056657
```

The output is to use a list generator.

Comment: found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945941/why-does-pandas-json-normalize-run-slower-than-my-hand-crafted-loop)  on the topic

Comment: updated answer, with tests.

Comment: If you convert the list into Series in the `list generator`, then on 1700 rows I get almost same times for `apply`, `transform ` and `list generator`.

Comment: I agree that I rushed with json_normalize. He is the slowest. Now rechecked in the list generator it turns out 28-29 times faster than in apply. Or are you using the list generator in some other way?

Comment: posted my findings in an answer. I am also taking into account the conversion time of a list into a Series

Comment: As far as I understand the author already has a series.

Comment: the author wants to get a Series.. so to compare different methods - they all have to produce a Series

Comment: can also immediately place the result of the list generator in a column: calFilteredDf['startTime'] = [i['dateTime'] for i in calFilteredDf[0]]

Answer (score 2):

`apply`, `transform` and `list comprehension` methods produce similar speeds on large datasets (with more than 2000 rows), and they all are quite fast! On smaller datasets (especially < 1000 rows) list comprehension beats other methods.

**Edit:** Another method I've found - to use `.str[]`.

Timings using the [`perfplot`](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/0.2.1/) package:

```py
def gen(n):
    return pd.Series([{'date': None, 'dateTime': '2021-08-12T09:30'}] * n)
```

```py
def using_apply(s):
    return s.apply(lambda x: x['dateTime'])

def using_transform(s):
    return s.transform(lambda x: x['dateTime'])

def using_list_comprehension(s):
    return pd.Series([i['dateTime'] for i in s])

def using_str(s):
    return s.str['dateTime']
```

```py
import perfplot

perfplot.plot(
    setup=gen,
    kernels=[using_apply, using_transform, using_list_comprehension, using_str],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(4, 24)],
    equality_check=None
)
```

[image]

Comparison with the `pd.json_normalize()` method only on small datasets (because it is too slow on the large ones):

```py
def using_json_normalize(s):
    return pd.json_normalize(s)['dateTime']

perfplot.plot(
    setup=gen,
    kernels=[using_apply, using_transform, using_list_comprehension, using_str, using_json_normalize],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(4, 12)],
    equality_check=None
)
```

[image]